# Why do AR(1) times series generated by two methods look similar but have different variance estimate in Python

Tags: time-series, python, autoregressive, signal-processing

I come across one question when I use two ways to generate AR(1) sequences. 
By definition, AR(1) sequence is

$x_t = \phi_1 x_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t,\quad \varepsilon_t\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$
I found one function from `statsmodels.tsa.arima_process.arma_generate_sample` to generate the time series. In addition, it is possible to write the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ first and then generate the series $x = \Sigma e$. To make the two results comparable, I modify the function from built-in function so that they accept the same random error $e$. It also requires `numpy, signal, stats` modules to implement.

I set the seed as `np.random.seed(100)` and the series length is `300`. It seems that the series by built-in function is usually sharper than my own code. For built-in function, I set `ar=np.r_[1, -np.array([0.5])], ma = np.array([1]), scale=1`.

[[image: sample <span class=]$AR(1)$ time series">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN546.png)

And the variance of built-in and my own code is `1.38, 1.04`. 
I have two specific questions here.

> 1. Why do two methods produce slightly different results under the same parameter and seed setup?
>
> I am guessing `ma` parameter from the built-in function because when I tune it from `1` to `0.9`, their difference at peak is reduced. But I am not sure how it is related to the actual change?
>
> 2. Even though two time series look similar, why do their variance differ so much? (The true variance is 1 here.)

Finally, I will attach the code I use to produce two plots.

**Modified built-in function**

```py
        def arma_generate_sample_fix_randn(
            ar, ma, n_sample, rand_num, scale=1, axis=0, burnin=0
    ):

        if np.ndim(n_sample) == 0:
            n_sample = [n_sample]
        if burnin:
            # handle burin time for nd arrays, maybe there is a better trick in scipy.fft code
            newsize = list(n_sample)
            newsize[axis] += burnin
            newsize = tuple(newsize)
            fslice = [slice(None)] * len(newsize)
            fslice[axis] = slice(burnin, None, None)
            fslice = tuple(fslice)
        else:
            newsize = tuple(n_sample)
            fslice = tuple([slice(None)] * np.ndim(newsize))
        eta = scale * rand_num
        return signal.lfilter(ma, ar, eta, axis=axis)[fslice]
```

**Covariance matrix by my own code**

```py
        def create_toeplitz_cov_mat(sigma_sq, first_column_except_1):

            r"""
            sigma_sq: scalar_like,
            first_column_except_1: array_like, 1d-array, except diagonal 1.
            return:
                2d-array with dimension (len(first_column)+1, len(first_column)+1)
            """
            first_column = np.append(1, first_column_except_1)
            cov_mat = sigma_sq * linalg.toeplitz(first_column)
            return cov_mat

        def create_ar1_cov_mat(sigma_sq, rho, n):

            r"""
            sigma_sq: scalar
            rho: scalar, should be within -1 and 1.
            n: integer
            return: 2d-matrix of (n,n)
            """
            rho_tile = rho * np.ones([n - 1])
            first_column_except_1 = np.cumprod(rho_tile)
            cov_mat = create_toeplitz_cov_mat(sigma_sq, first_column_except_1)
            return cov_mat


        def generate_ar1_noise_close_fake(
            sigma_sq, rho, seq_length, std_noise
        ):
            cov_mat = create_ar1_cov_mat(sigma_sq, rho, seq_length)
            cov_half_mat = np.linalg.cholesky(cov_mat)
            ar1_noise = cov_half_mat @ std_noise
            del std_noise
            return ar1_noise
```

**Main**

```py
    rho = np.array([0.5])
    ma_1 = np.array([1])
    n_length = 300
    rand_n = np.random.normal(size=n_length)
    ar = np.r_[1, -rho]
    noise_arq_test_1 = BayesGenSeqObj.arma_generate_sample_fix_randn(
        ar, ma_1, n_length, rand_n, scale=1, axis=0, burnin=0
    )
    noise_arq_test_2 = BayesGenSeqObj.generate_ar1_noise_close_fake(
        1, rho, n_length, rand_n
    )
    print(np.var(noise_arq_test_1))
    print(np.var(noise_arq_test_2))
    noise_arq_test_diff = noise_arq_test_1 - noise_arq_test_2
    plt.figure()
    # plt.plot(np.linspace(0, size_num, num=size_num), rand_n[0, :], label='init-randn')
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0, n_length, num=n_length), noise_arq_test_1, label="built-in")
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0, n_length, num=n_length), noise_arq_test_2, label="I write it")
    # plt.plot(np.linspace(0, size_num, num=size_num), noise_arq_test_diff[0, :], label='diff')
    plt.legend(loc="upper right")
    plt.show()
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I guess is that in your model you set the long term variance equal to one, while arma_generate_sample has an innovation variance equal to one.

Comment: Does it have any difference?? I am not familiar with the innovation variance concept. Do you have any reference or clarification on it?

Comment: see var(x) for AR(1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Example:_An_AR(1)_process. It should be in most text books, but I don't have any right now. IIRC,`var(x) = var_u / (1 - sum(ar_coeffs **2)` where var_u is variance of residual or innovation.